# Why llvm can not auto-vectorize comparing two arrays and write result to vector<bool>?

Tags: c++, llvm, compiler-optimization, auto-vectorization

I want to compare two arrays and write the result to bitmap. Therefore, I tried the following code:

```cpp
void wtf(int *lhs, int *rhs, int len, std::vector<bool>& dst){
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        dst[i] = lhs[i] == rhs[i];
    }
}
```

In the [`compiler explorer`](https://godbolt.org/z/a9qfbjMbs), we can see that the above code is not vectorized. If we write the result to a boolean array, LLVM will vectorize it.

Why the above code can not be vectorized? What is the most efficient code to accomplish this task? I searched a lot and did not find the answer.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is a weird thing, and many people consider it to be a mistake. It's allowed to store bools as single bit (instead of using full byte), which makes is very clunky. No wonder compiler misses an optimisation here.

Comment: I'm guessing `vector<unsigned char>` would vectorize fine, too.. See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

Comment: You know `vector<bool>` is a bit-array, right?  The C++ functions involved are a lot of code for a compiler to "see through".  The actual asm needed on x86-64 is `pcmpeqd` / `movmskps` to get 4 bits at a time, and some scalar shift / OR to combine into 8-bit chunks.  (AVX2 with 32-byte vectors could get an 8-bit mask from 8 ints at once.)  Or compare 4 vectors and combine with 2x `packssdw` / 1x `packsswb` before `pmovmskb` to get one 16-bit mask result.  But IDK what chunk size the `vector<bool>` specialization uses internally.  (no luck wth x86-64-v4 or GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/b4PKnWbzT)

Comment: Off-topic: AFAIK there are SIMD instructions which can operate on bit-array. So from CPU perspective it is possible to vectorize that. I guessing compiler is not able to vectorize into bit-array yet.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Howard Hinnant describes the situation well: https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool - a bit-array is a useful data structure that it's good to have in the C++ standard library.  `vector<bool>` is a terrible choice of name for it, though; that's the mistake.  x86-64 SIMD (SSE2 and AVX2) can very naturally and efficiently generate bitmaps from SIMD compares, so in theory it's an efficient data structure.  But in practice the C++ wrappers (both libstdc++ and libc++) are too complex for auto-vectorization to see through, it seems.

Comment: @MarekR: Yes, as I commented, it's pretty straightforward to manually vectorize this with SSE2, e.g. with `_mm_movemask_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(cmp_result))` or better with pack.  And also doable efficiently with AVX2, although the in-lane (two separate 128-bit shuffles) behaviour of pack instructions requires some extra work if you don't go straight to scalar 8 bits at a time.  AVX-512 natively uses masks, so just a couple `vpcmpeqd k1, zmm, [mem]` and `kunpckwd` then `kmovd [rcx], k1` should be very efficient on Zen 4, or maybe use 256-bit vectors with AVX-512 on Intel with a bit more unpacking.

Comment: @PeterCordes So it looks like the `vector<bool>` is too complex to perform auto-vectorization. It sounds counterintuitive that c++/llvm does not optimize this case because it is pretty common 

Comment: It's maybe not *that* common; `std::vector<bool>` is fairly unpopular.  You might have more luck auto-vectorizing a loop that works in chunks of 8, 16, or 32 elements, building up a mask in a `uint32_t` and doing one assignment through a pointer, instead of many separate RMWs with complicated indexing to break down a bit-index into pointer and shift count.  IIRC, there have been some previous SO Q&As where people had some success at getting something to auto-vectorize to a `pmovmskb` or `movmskps`.